# Populating data based on users selection

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do you populate data coming from SQL server based on users request?

Example:

I have a page with about 50 links(all user links) and I want to be able to have the user click on their link and bring another page(template I believe) with all their data. The catch here is that I don't want to create 50 pages(one of each user).

How can I accomplish this in ASP.NET C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple as creating an aspx page and a model.

1. Profile.aspx - this page contains all the view display for the current user or the requesting user. You can pass the user id through the link you had. Example:

> ```
> <a href="Profile.aspx?userId=123">John Doe</a>
> ```

1. Now in the page load or the controller (MVC) - code behind you can use that id to retrieve the details of the user and start to populate to your aspx page. Example:

> `txtName.Text = UserModel.Name`

Or if your are using MVC for the web application it will be easy as naming the controls and setup the model in your view aspx.

Comment: First thank you for your response. Now, how can I get fetch the data based on the userId=123 in the Profile.aspx page? what controls should i use?

Comment: Are you using MVC for this? Or just an ordinary web application?

Comment: Ok, I might as well give you a sample for this it seems you are a noob for this task.  Will get back to you for this.

Comment: thank you, I'm new to web development. I was assign to this task without getting my consent on it and now I'm stuck with it.

Comment: You might want to install MVC in you machine while waiting, here are the links.

[Download MVC 2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=C9BA1FE1-3BA8-439A-9E21-DEF90A8615A9&displaylang=en)

[MVC Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials)

Comment: Here is a sample [app](http://www.MegaShare.com/3243074), its created in MVC.  Good luck with it. If you read the tutorials all will have make sense from UI to your Data layer.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I think this site could get you started: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials

There should be very similar examples to what you would like to do. Explaining it here would just duplicate existing good material.

If you are completely new to programming, try a C# tutorial first, for example: http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson01.aspx